# using Find*.cmake without adding it to cmake modules folder

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I want to use FindAntTweakBar.cmake that it becomes able to find the anttweakbar, but I dont have administration access to the cmake's modules folder, so I cannot copy it there. Is there any way to include it and not copy it in the Modules folder? I am using the cmake-gui in the windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to a folder of your choice within your project instead, and modify the CMAKE_MODULES_PATH  for that specific project in your CMakeLists.txt.

For instance, if you were to put it into a folder "[location of top-level CMakeLists.txt]/cmake", you would issue:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```